# Core Data "Codegen" for existing project in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, core-data

So, I understand that Core Data's new "Codegen" feature puts class files into "Derived Data" instead of your project... which is nice.

However, recently in the past it created two separate classes... one that you could manually delete and regenerate, and another that could contain your code/methods for those objects.

I tried turning "Codegen" but it doesn't seem to create the file for our code. **How is this supposed to work if we want to add methods to Core Data objects?** — Does anyone know how to get it working like before, just without the extra duplicate files, or is there some reason we shouldn't be doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add your own code to the class then just set the Codegen dropdown to Category/Extension and it will only generate `MyClass+CoreDataProperties.h` and `MyClass+CoreDataProperties.m` into Derived Data, which you then need to include at the end of your MyClass.h header file, like before.

btw; it can be a bit finicky getting it to work properly as this setting sometimes doesn't save after you change it, so try save manually before you go to another file and then check the setting saved after. Also clean your project before you build or it might not generate the files.

Comment: OK, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: So, doing it as a protocol/extension works like before, but the class files themselves are still missing in that process. It's sort of weird. It's not as bad when it's a subclass because you can sort of copy and paste out of a another subclass as a template or worst case from the parent, but for root classes there's no template available?

Comment: You can still use Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass to get the class files

Comment: Hmm, yeah you're right. I wouldn't have found that. But, it does this weird sort of "This file was automatically generated and should not be edited" stuff even in the class file.

Comment: When I generate the subclasses manually the +CoreDataClass.h extensions are created but not the base classes.  Is this the intended behavior?